# Sorting two dimensional table by reordering rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

Is it possible and if it is, how to sort two dimensional table, by reordering columns and rows, and using only these two operations, that table's biggest numbers are concentrated in top-left corner?
Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

For example, we can use this table:

```
     Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
Row 1    2        4        5       
Row 2    3        2        6
Row 3    7        2        6
```

Result I think would be this, but I am not sure:

```
     Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
Row 1    7        6        2       
Row 2    3        6        2
Row 3    2        5        4
```

For now, I only thought about summing rows and columns and sorting them to left-top descending.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: I would urge to read your question and ask yourself if you think you would be able to answer this based only on the information provided.

Comment: @baraka . . . You are describing *matrix* operations.  Such operations do not make sense on *sets* where the rows have no ordering.

Comment: Ok, forget about sql, just algorithmically is it possible to sort this matrix according rules I gave? @Sean Lange what more information you need? For me, everything is clear.

Comment: I don't understand any of the logic to be honest. Swapping whole row and swapping whole column. What does that mean? So we have some sample data...what should it look like when you are done?

Comment: @SeanLange, thank you for response, the analogy is Rubik's cube, only two dimensional, you can only swap columns and rows with other columns and rows, maybe now is more understandable?

Comment: So, it looks like you can flip a column upside down (reverse the order) and move a column. Can I flip a row and move a row? How many iterations of flipping and moving columns and rows does one get? Like... I feel that the last row `row 3` should be `4   5   2`. Since that would further concentrate higher values to top-left.

Comment: If you are reordering the number up/down, then the whole row gets up/down. If you are reordering the number left/right, then the whole column gets left/right.

Comment: I understand now. I have to agree with Gordon that doing this in t-sql is not a good approach. This type of manipulation is much better suited to a programming language instead of a data retrieval language. But assuming each row has a primary key then it is certainly feasible.

Comment: @JNevill - so far as I understand it, you can't flip a column upside down *unless* you also rearrange the other columns so that each row is kept intact during that operation. Similarly, if you rearrange a row, you have to also rearrange all other rows during that same operation. Best way to see it is that, if there's a row containing, say, `{2,6,7}` in the input, then there'll definitely be such a row in the final output, although the values may appear in a different order (there is, row 3 input, row 1 output). Similarly, each input column is also represented in the output as a column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. That's a great explanation!

Comment: Primary key is ColumnId and RowId, the main problem is algorithm and the result would be the most efficient sort of this table, because in certain situations, you can't sort in perfect order.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I am not native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a MatLab guy when it comes to matrix manipulations, but perhaps this may help.

Here we use a TVF to create a dynamic EAV structure.  If you can't use a function, it is a small matter to go in-line.

Also, the final pivot can be dynamic if needed

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Column1 int,Column2 int,Column3 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(2,4,5),       
(3,2,6),
(7,2,6)

;with cte as (
        Select RowNr=Dense_Rank() over (Order By RowTotal Desc,Entity )
              ,ColNr=Dense_Rank() over (Order By ColTotal Desc,Attribute)
              ,Value
        From (
                Select * 
                      ,RowTotal = max(cast(Value as float)) over(Partition By Entity)
                      ,ColTotal = max(cast(Value as float)) over(Partition By Attribute)
                 From  [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)),* From @YourTable for XML RAW))
             ) A
)
Select [1] Col1,[2] Col2,[3] Col3
From cte
Pivot (max(Value) For [ColNr] in ([1],[2],[3]) ) p
```

**Returns**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
7       6       2
3       6       2
2       5       4
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-EAV](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    with cteKey(k) as (Select Top 1 xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') From @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow) Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt))    

    Select Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(50)')
          ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
    From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
    Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt)
    Where xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not In (Select k From cteKey)
)
-- Notes:  First Field in Query will be the Entity
-- Select * From [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select UTCDate=GetUTCDate(),* From sys.dm_os_sys_info for XML RAW))
```

Comment: @baraka This will support any two dimenional array.  You may notice that no fields are specified.  For any n-array, the final pivot would have to be dynamic.  I will add option if needed